# How to use $lt in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get posts where the number of reports is less than 10% of the total number of users. Currently, each post has a default reportsLength of 0.

```
const Users = await User.find();
    // console.log(Users.length);
    const lt = Math.ceil(0.1 * Users.length);
    // console.log(Math.ceil(lt));
    const posts = await Post.find({
      reportsLength: { $lt: lt },
      type: req.params.type,
    })
```

This is the posts model

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    reports: [
      {
        user: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User",
        },
      },
    ],
    reportsLength: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
const numOfUsers = await User.countDocuments();
const lt = Math.ceil(0.1 * numOfUsers);
const posts = await Post.find({
    reportsLength: { $lt: lt },
    type: req.params.type,
})
```